# Is question about "downloading courses from PluralSight" off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I've wrote a script in order to download courses/videos from PluralSight, including subtitle *for myself*.

[image]

Now I want to ask my own question with an answer to share the script. But I worry about: Is it an off-topic or not?

Because all of the courses on PluralSight are not free, so everyone needs a subscription to learn. Although Visual Studio supports 2 free months to view all of the courses for each user. But after that, they still need to renew the subscription...

And the question is: *How to download all of the courses from PluralSight in 2 free months?*

I think the question is valid because:

- Question about programming: *How to do that?*
- The answer explains the way using programming language (javascript): *You can try this...*

But I'm not sure about the content. It looks like *stealing courses from PluralSight*. I just want to share the script.

Should I ask that question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't **close** questions because they're potentially illegal, but don't be surprised if you get a heap of downvotes thrown your way because the community doesn't like what you're doing.

Ultimately, though, there's not enough meat to your question to begin with.  All you're asking is how you accomplish a task, which - while under most circumstances could be seen as *enough* to ask a question on Stack Overflow - makes the question more dupe fodder than anything else; surely someone *else* has broached the subject of website scraping with JavaScript beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

I do not think this is a valid question on Stack Overflow:

- you are most probably not allowed to programmatically download all courses so that you circumvent the 2-month limitation
- you are not asking about how to do a *focused* programming task (e.g., how to download the video content from a specific stream type)

However, if you have a fully working code that you want to be reviewed, you may consider posting it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.